# Does this series converge and what is its value?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Given the following series

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2\alpha +k -1}\left\{\frac{\alpha \cdot (\alpha + 1) \cdots (\alpha+k-1)}{k!} \right\}
$$

with $\alpha \in (\frac 12, 1)$.

Does this series converge? If so, what is it's limit?

---

This is alternating series, so the series must be convergent, since the $\alpha \cdot (\alpha + 1) \cdots (\alpha+k-1)$ and $k!$ cancel out termwise, with $\frac{(-1)^k}{2\alpha +k -1}$ left, so it's an alternating sequence that converges to zero.

We can also rewrite this series in terms of the beta function

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{B(\alpha, k)}\left\{\frac{1}{2\alpha+k-1}\right\}
$$

Is there a way to approach the limit of this series?

Thanks!

Comment: Since
$$\frac 1 {2 \alpha + k - 1} =
\frac 1 {2 \alpha - 1} \frac {(2 \alpha - 1)_k} {(2 \alpha)_k},$$
we have a series expansion of a ${_2 F_1}$ function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI,

Start from:

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2\alpha +k -1}\left\{\frac{\alpha \cdot (\alpha + 1) \cdots (\alpha+k-1)}{k!} \right\}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2\alpha+k-1}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+k)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(k)}$

Known that $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+k)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}=(\alpha)_k $- Pochhammer symbol. We can also use on of the definitions of the incomplete beta function:

$\beta_{-z}(a,b)=z^a\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(1-b)_k}{k!(k+a)}z^k$

Compare this with the original sum we get:

$z=-1$

$a=2\alpha$

and

$b=1-\alpha$

So

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2\alpha +k -1}\left\{\frac{\alpha \cdot (\alpha + 1) \cdots (\alpha+k-1)}{k!} \right\}=-(-1)^{-2\alpha}\beta_{-1}\left(2\alpha-1, 1-\alpha\right) $

Comment: Thanks for the incomplete beta! Probably $(-1)^{-2\alpha}$ missing in the last formula?

Comment: It is equal to 1, $\frac{1}{((-1)^2)^\alpha}$. Do you accept my answere?

Comment: Are you sure? It’s the root of unity, so it’s complex. For example, $(-1)^(3/2)=-i$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I skipped over it.

Comment: Thank you for +1.